# How to update the textbox based upon the DataGrid column?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, textbox

I have tried to implement some trick with DataGrid column. In my design I have a TextBox behind the grid column. If I resize that column means I have to alter the size if the text box to place relevant to my column. I have tried it by using update layout event and also using Element name binding for the column with the help of the converter.. But I am not able to achieve it by my concept. Width and Layout process occurs only on resize the column header with right side grip.

Please find my code snippet

```
 <Grid>
        <StackPanel Width="600">
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" ColumnWidth="*">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding OrderID}" Header="ID"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="C.ID" Width="150"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" Header="c.Name" Width="150"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Height="20" Grid.Column="1" Width="150" Name="txtBox"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGrid.LayoutUpdated += DataGrid_LayoutUpdated;

}

private void DataGrid_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBox.Width= Convert.ToDouble(dataGrid.Columns[2].Width.Value);
}
```

Comment: Please show your XAML, and show what you tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: So how is the column resized?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in xaml. give your column a name and bind the TextBox `Width` property to the `ActualWidth` property of the datagrid column

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Width="600">
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" ColumnWidth="*">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Binding="{Binding OrderID}" Header="ID"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerID}" Header="C.ID" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" Header="c.Name" Width="150"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Height="20" Grid.Column="1" Name="txtBox" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ID}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Bala have this answer helped you?